# Can you ride in the same car in LEGO City Undercover for switch?

Tags: lego-city-undercover

Is it possible to ride in the same car when playing co-op in LEGO City Undercover on Switch?

Answer (score 1):

Bought the game now and the conclusion is the following. 
You can ride in the same car if:
It’s a bus or limousine. 
One player can stand at the roof on a car but if the car crash the player will fall of.

Answer (score -1):

No, generally not. Some vehicles do let you have multiple people in them, I think. But those are special cases.